# Default value % calculation not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding some calculate part, I set the default value 15 to this text box `txtVatno`
I want to calculate default value, I removed the default value, and I can enter value, now calculate working fine, but I want to calculate default 15%

**Calculate**

```
GrossAmount = 1500

  VAT(+) = 15
```

### 225

---

**Gross Amount**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrossAmount" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeydown="return (!((event.keyCode>=65 && event.keyCode <= 95) || event.keyCode >= 106) && event.keyCode!=32);" Enabled="false"   ></asp:TextBox>
```

**Vat= 15%**

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtVatno" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control contentTransparent"   OnTextChanged="txtVatno_TextChanged" value="15" ></asp:TextBox>`

---

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTax" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control "   ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

---

**CODE PART**

```
private void calculate()
        {

     txtTax.Text = (Double.Parse(txtGrossAmount.Text) * Double.Parse(txtVatno.Text) / 100.0).ToString("#0.00");
                if (txtGrossAmount.Text == "")
                {
                    txtGrossAmount.Text = "0";
                }

}
```

---

```
protected void txtVatno_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculate();
        }
```

Comment: Is this 15% always a default value or you can change? It seems fine.

Comment: Sir its is always default, no anyone to change it

Comment: So what doesn't work right now?

Comment: im set the default value but not display calculate , its not working correctly,

Comment: Check my answer below and call the `calculate()` method on `Page_Load`

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example which you can check again.

Answer (score 0):

For the `default` to work, call the `calculate()` method on `Page_Load`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    calculate();
}
```

Also you can change the `calculate` method as below by grouping the percentage with parenthesis `(Double.Parse(txtVatno.Text) / 100.0))`.

```
private void calculate()
{
   if (txtGrossAmount.Text == "")
                {
                    txtGrossAmount.Text = "0";
                }

     txtTax.Text = (Double.Parse(txtGrossAmount.Text) * (Double.Parse(txtVatno.Text) / 100.0)).ToString("#0.00");


}
```

Comment: @SamD What happened?

Comment: Page not load, im debug this , i had error ` Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: In the `calculate()` method, move the if statement to top. This will fix the issue

Comment: I have updated the same. Check the `calculate()` method and change accordingly.

Comment: Can you edit your question with all the latest code and I will check?

Comment: sir im try it not work.  Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Sir, this page had some another calculate part

Comment: Can you post all the code in aspx and code behind file?